# Jquery not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery

I had make one code in jquery for dynamically add component in Page

```
var counter = 1;
var delCnt = 0;
$(function() {
    $('#linkAddLot').click(function() {
        counter = eval(document.getElementById("hdnTotLot").value);
        delCnt = eval(document.getElementById("hdnDelLot").value);
        if((eval(counter-delCnt))>=5){
            $('span.#lotMsg').css("visibility","visible");
            $('span.#lotMsg').css("color","red");
            $('span.#lotMsg').html('Already 5 (Five) Lot!!!');
        } else {
            $('span.#lotMsg').css("visibility","collapse");
            var htmlEle = "<tr id='trLot_"+ (counter+1) +"'>"+
                "<td class='t-align-center'><input type='checkbox' name='packagedetail_"+ (counter+1) +"' id='chkPackageDetail_"+ (counter+1) +"' value='"+ (counter+1) +"'/></td>"+
                "<td class='t-align-center'><input name='lotno_"+ (counter+1) +"' type='text' class='formTxtBox_1' id='txtLotNo_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='width:80px;' onBlur='chkLotNoBlank(this);chkLotNo(this);'/><span id='msgLotNo_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='color: red; ' >&nbsp;</span></td>"+
                "<td class='t-align-center'><textarea name='lotdesc_"+ (counter+1) +"' cols='20' rows='3' class='formTxtBox_1' id='txtLotDesc_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='width:250px;' onBlur='chkLotDetBlank(this);'></textarea><span id='msgLotDesc_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='color: red; '>&nbsp;</span></td>"+
                "<td class='t-align-center'><input name='quantity_"+ (counter+1) +"' type='text' class='formTxtBox_1' id='txtQuantity_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='width:80px;' onBlur='chkQtyBlank(this);'/><span id='msgLotQty_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='color: red; '>&nbsp;</span></td>"+
                "<td class='t-align-center'><input name='unit_"+ (counter+1) +"' type='text' class='formTxtBox_1' id='txtUnit_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='width:80px;' onBlur='chkUnitBlank(this);'/><span id='msgLotUnit_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='color: red; '>&nbsp;</span></td>"+
                "<td class='t-align-center'><input name='estimatecost_"+ (counter+1) +"' type='text' class='formTxtBox_1' id='txtEstimateCost_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='width:80px;' onChange='setPkgEstCost(this);' onBlur='chkEstBlank(this);'/><span id='msgLotCost_"+ (counter+1) +"' style='color: red; '>&nbsp;</span></td>"+
                "</tr>";
            $("#tblLots").append(htmlEle);
            document.getElementById("hdnTotLot").value = (counter+1);
        }
    });
});
```

Here i had made onBlur function on `onBlur='chkLotNoBlank(this);chkLotNo(this);'` on txtLotNo but in IE8 its cant work,

if i wil run it in IE 7 and firefox i works fine,  and alos if i will work in windows 7 pre installed IE8 version IE8.0.7600.16385 , but it cant work if i will try out in windows 2003 compatible IE 8.0.6001.18702, so can anyone give me solution for this?

Comment: What is the code of the functions `chkLotNoBlank` and `chkLotNo`? I don't see those posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what the issue is -- but using those evals is definitely funky.  It's best to not use eval if you don't have to, it consumes a lot of resources.

Try this:

```
var counter = 1; 
var delCnt = 0; 

$(function() { 
    $('#linkAddLot').click(function() { 
        counter = parseInt($("#hdnTotLot").val(),10); 
        delCnt = parseInt($("#hdnDelLot").val(),10); 
        if(((counter-delCnt)>=5){ 
            $('span.#lotMsg').css("visibility","visible"); 
            $('span.#lotMsg').css("color","red"); 
            $('span.#lotMsg').html('Already 5 (Five) Lot!!!'); 
        } else { 
            $('span.#lotMsg').css("visibility","collapse"); 
            var htmlEle = ""+ ""+ " "+ " "+ " "+ " "+ " "+ ""; 
            $("#tblLots").append(htmlEle); 
            $("#hdnTotLot").val(counter+1); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and guidance, but i really thanks to you if you will find solution for my actual problem.

Comment: I need the actual code for the assignment of your blur event handler and the blur handlers themselves to provide you with a possible solution.

Comment: ah, onBlur="someFunc(this);"  function someFunc(elm){ if($(elm).val() == "") alert(empty);}

Comment: more friendly is $('elm').blur(function(){ if($(this).val()=="") alert(empty);});

Answer (score -1):

You have the following code:

```
$('span.#lotMsg').css("visibility","visible"); 
$('span.#lotMsg').css("color","red"); 
$('span.#lotMsg').html('Already 5 (Five) Lot!!!');
```

wouldn't it be better to shortern this to:

```
$('span.#lotMsg').css("visibility","visible").css("color","red").html('Already 5 (Five) Lot!!!');
```

Comment: This doesn't address the actual question, though.  This type of suggestion would be better suited as a comment to the question.